# How to secure RESTful API

Tags: api, security

Guys,

I am opening up a bunch of RESTful API, mostly `GET` at the moment, not modifying anything in the database.

I am planning to use this in our own mobile app, also to one of two trusted developers in the android applications they make.

I would like to know what's the possible & easiest way to secure the API to only the applications I authorize.

What's the best way to do that? I am using Rails 3.2

Comment: +1 Good question. Want to know the answer, too.

Comment: You probably want to use an API key. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350299/rails-plugin-for-api-key-secret-key-signing).